# disable-infobars argument unable to hide the infobar with the message "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software" with ChromeDriver v2.36

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I just updated ChromeDriver to newest version - 2.36. 
In previous versions I've set:

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
```

and the "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software" warning bar wasn't displayed. With the same option set, I'm keep seeing it. Do you know how to disable this from appearing in the newest ChromeDriver?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like people have the same problem on official Chrome Driver 2.36 Google thread.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromedriver-users/Tf3vzBMEzHg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New version of ChromeDriver has been released - 2.37. 
It again supports:

```
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
```

Answer (score 5):

`disable-infobars` flag has been removed in latest Chrome => https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/d869ab3350d8ebd95222b4a47adf87ce3d3214b1

Comment: Any replacement?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get rid of the message by adding the following...

```vb
    chromeOptions.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation")
```

This in turn causes a popup in Chrome titled "Disable developer mode extensions".  I am able to close this popup in VB.NET by calling `CloseChromeDialogDisableDeveloperModeExtensions()` method below at the appropriate time(s).

I hope this helps!

```vb
    Private Declare Auto Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
    Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" (hWnd As IntPtr, wMsg As Int32, wParam As Int32, lParam As String) As Int32

    Private Sub CloseChromeDialogDisableDeveloperModeExtensions()
        Try
            Const WM_CLOSE As Integer = 16
            Dim popupHandle As IntPtr = FindWindow("Chrome_WidgetWin_1", "Disable developer mode extensions")

            If popupHandle <> New IntPtr(0) Then
                SendMessage(popupHandle, WM_CLOSE, 0, Nothing)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            'swallow exception
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

`disable-infobars` flag has been removed but you can get rid of the message by adding the following:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches",Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));    
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

This work for me and I hope works for you too.

Comment: Thanks. It helped. Can you eleborate on what those experimentalOptions acctuly do?

Comment: This worked for me with Chrome v76 and ChromeDriver v76.0.3809.68.

Answer (score 1):

You saw it right.

Passing the argument `disable-infobars` no more suppresses the infobar with text as ***`Chrome is being controlled by automated test software`*** with **ChromeDriver v2.36**.

As per [https://crrev.com/528386](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/d869ab3350d8ebd95222b4a47adf87ce3d3214b1) the flag `--disable-infobars` was removed on *Wed Jan 10 19:44:29 2018* as this flag is no longer needed by the perf testing infrastructure and can be misused for malicious purposes, so remove it.

```
Remove --disable-infobars.

This flag is no longer needed by the perf testing infrastructure and can be
misused for malicious purposes, so remove it.

BUG=none
TEST=none
```

This change landed with *ChromeDriver v2.36* on *2018-03-02* which supported *Chrome v63-65*. Hence while using *ChromeDriver v2.36* the infobar is no more getting supressed.

---

But as per [Infobars cannot be disabled - breaks coordinate assumptions in Selenium tests](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=820453#c6) the **`--disable-infobars`** was back on *Mar 20 2018*.

### Solution

With *ChromeDriver v2.36* if you are unable to supress the infobar with text as ***`Chrome is being controlled by automated test software`***, you need to upgrade to **`ChromeDriver v2.38`** of *2018-04-17* which supported *Chrome v65-67*

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. Thanks for trying, though.

Comment: I tried that now on chrome version 64 and your solution worked, after update chrome to version 65 it stopped working. Maybe we should wait for newer version of chromedriver.

Comment: This topic relates to Chrome Driver version 2.36. This is the newest, not 2.35. Chrome v65.

Comment: @KarolMajewski For the time being I would avoid commenting on _ChromeDriver v2.36_. ChromeDriver v2.36 was in alpha/beta for a bit longer wrt the previous releases. So I am a bit skeptical and would advise you the stable _ChromeDriver v2.35_.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. It works fine

```
`ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars"); 
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);`
```

Comment: Depends on the chromedriver version number.

Answer (score 0):

A latest working example in Java:

```
options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
```

Tested in Chrome Version 80

Answer (score 0):

Streamlined solution:

```
options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", new String[]{"enable-automation"});
```