# How to open Chrome browser maximized and supressing the infobars through ChromeOptions and addArguments using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options

I am using Chrome driver on mac, and when opening the browser I have these options

```
WebDriver driver; 
@Before public void setup() { 
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
    options.addArguments("use-fake-ui-for-media-stream"); 
    options.addArguments("--disable-web-security"); 
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized"); 
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars"); 
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/animanukyan/Drivers/chromedriver"); 
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options); 
}
```

but non of them seems to work, browser opens not maximized, infobars are there...

Comment: How did you create the `Webdriver`?

Comment: yes, please share the command you used to initialise the driver.

Answer (score 0):

Using *ChromeDriver* to open *Chrome* **maximized** and without **infobars**:

Previously we handled through the *argument* **`disable-infobars`** and you can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to get rid of the infobar “Chrome is being controlled by automated test software” through Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52614592/how-to-get-rid-of-the-infobar-chrome-is-being-controlled-by-automated-test-soft/52614965#52614965)
- [disable-infobars argument unable to hide the infobar with the message “Chrome is being controlled by automated test software” with ChromeDriver v2.36](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49169990/disable-infobars-argument-unable-to-hide-the-infobar-with-the-message-chrome-is/49170096#49170096)

But from *Chrome v76.x* onwards to suppress the **infobars** you have to:

- Use an instance of *ChromeOptions* and *addArguments* to `start-maximized`.
- Use *ExperimentalOption* to `enable-automation`.
- Use *ExperimentalOption* to set `useAutomationExtension` as `false`.
- You can find a detailed discussion in [Unable to hide “Chrome is being controlled by automated software” infobar within Chrome v76](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57298901/unable-to-hide-chrome-is-being-controlled-by-automated-software-infobar-within/57317146#57317146)
- Code Block:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

  public class A_Chrome 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("start-maximized");
          options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
          options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
          WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options);
          driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
          System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
          driver.quit();
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Google
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: ChromeOptions]

Comment: This worked for infobar, thanks!. And is there a way to allow camera access?

Comment: and is there a way to allow camera access as well?